# Why do I need to click twice on the TouchableOpacity?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, view, touchableopacity

I want to create a button where if you click on it you copy the color of the said button.
But I need to click twice in order to copy my color (the first time I copy nothing)
Can someone help me or tell me where I made the error?
Here is my code :

```
  const [couleur, setCouleur] = useState("");
  async function cop() {
    await navigator.clipboard.writeText(couleur);
    alert("Couleur copiée");
  }
```

```
           <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                  setCouleur("black");
                  cop();
                }}
              >
                <View
                  style={{
                    width: "100%",
                    height: 30,
                    backgroundColor: "#ADDAD4",
                  }}
                >
                  <Text style={styles.textcol}>green-8</Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
```

```
 textcol: {
    fontSize: 12,
    marginLeft: "75%",
    fontWeight: "300",
    textAlign: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    alignSelf: "center",
    marginTop: "2%",
    color: "white",
    fontStyle: "italic",
  },
```

Comment: It seems to me that the setCouleur() is executed after the cop() so at first it's blank, then it is the setCouleur of before. If someone know how to choose the order of the functions, please tell me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do 2 things:

```
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
              setCouleur("#black");
            }}
          >
```

as well as add an UseEffect at the beggining:

```
  useEffect(() => {
if (couleur !== "") {
  cop();
} },[couleur]);
```